# How to fix this type error when computing a list of divisors?

Tags: function, integer, ocaml, division

I am working on the following exercise:

> Define a function `libDiv` which computes the list of natural divisors of some positive integer.
>
> First define `libDivInf`, such that `libDivInf n i` is the list of divisors of `n` which are lesser than or equal to `i`
>
> ```
> libDivInf : int -> int -> int list
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> (liDivInf 20 4) = [4;2;1] 
> (liDivInf 7 5)  = [1] 
> (liDivInf 4 4)  = [4;2;1]
> ```

Here's is my attempt:

```
let liDivInf : int -> int -> int list = function 
    (n,i) -> if i = 0 then []   (*ERROR LINE*)
      else 
      if (n mod i) = 0 (* if n is dividable by i *) 
      then 
        i::liDivInf n(i-1)
      else 
        liDivInf n(i-1);; 

let liDiv : int -> int list = function 
    n -> liDivInf n n;;
```

I get:

```
ERROR: this pattern matches values of type 'a * 'b ,but a pattern
was expected which matches values of type int
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: SO is an English-only website. Please translate your question into English. See [ask] for more, and [this meta post in particular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange/13684#13684).

Comment: you are accepting a tuple as a function argument; `(n,i)`, but calling the same function with two integer values (first `n`, then `i`), which is different

Answer (score 2):

You've stated that the signature of `liDivInf` needs to be `int -> int -> int list`. This is a function which takes two curried arguments and returns a list, but then bound that to a function which accepts a single tuple with two ints. And then you've recursively called it in the curried fashion. This is leading to your type error.

The `function` keyword can only introduce a function which takes a single argument. It is primarily useful when you need to pattern-match on that single argument. The `fun` keyboard can have multiple arguments specified, but does not allow for pattern-matching the same way.

It is possible to write a function without using *either*.

```
let foo = function x -> x + 1
```

Can just be:

```
let foo x = x + 1
```

Similarly:

```
let foo = function x -> function y -> x + y
```

Can be written:

```
let foo x y = x + y
```

You've also defined a recursive function, but not included the `rec` keyword. It seems you're looking for something much more like the following slightly modified version of your attempt.

```ml
let rec liDivInf n i =
  if i = 0 then 
    []
  else if (n mod i) = 0 then 
    i::liDivInf n (i-1)
  else 
    liDivInf n (i-1)
```